# Android rotating bitmap around its center

Tags: java, android, 3d, android-canvas

I am trying to rotate regular bitmap around X, Y and Z axis using canvas and matrix. I could use OpenGL but I think it would be overkill to achieve such a simple effect as I am pretty sure this is possible using just canvas, bitmap and matrix.

I tried using camera and its rotateX, rotateY and rotateZ method and then applying that matrix to canvas but for some reason I can get it to rotate the bitmap around it center!

I can't find method to change the rotate origin so I decided to translate the camera so its at center of bitmap and afterwards translate it back, but whatever I try the bitmap doesn't get translated by its center...[image]

```
            camera.save();

            camera.translate(-(team.getWidth() / 2), (team.getHeight() / 2), 0f);

            rotateY += 1f;

            camera.rotateY(rotateY);

            camera.translate((team.getWidth() / 2), -(team.getHeight() / 2), 0f);

            camera.applyToCanvas(canvas);

            camera.restore();

            /* code that has nothing to do with this..(fading) */

            canvas.drawBitmap(team, null, rect, paint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate3DAnimation is the answer for you. Here is the [class](http://source-android.frandroid.com/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.java)

And here is the tutorial too: 
[Tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) of 3D flip

Comment: Thank you, thank you and once more THANK YOU! :) It worked perfect, it only would be nice to hear why my solution didn't work? What is it with pre translation and post translation?

Comment: Matrix Translation calculting "formulas" for transformation. [Matrix class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preTranslate(float, float)). Just wondering, You have taken Linear Algebra course? It´s a good base if you going to play with animations and OpenGL

Comment: No I haven't, I am pretty much self taught in this field. I ordered linear algebra book a while ago tho, hopefully going to fix the situation.